# Kubernetes: All proxying not working

Tags: kubernetes

So I have a service like as follow:

```
{
 "kind": "Service",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "monitoring-grafana",
    "namespace": "kube-system",
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-grafana",
    "uid": "be0f72b2-c482-11e5-a22c-fa163ebc1085",
    "resourceVersion": "143360",
    "creationTimestamp": "2016-01-26T23:15:51Z",
    "labels": {
      "kubernetes.io/cluster-service": "true",
      "kubernetes.io/name": "monitoring-grafana"
    }
  },
  "spec": {
    "ports": [
      {
        "protocol": "TCP",
        "port": 80,
        "targetPort": 3000,
        "nodePort": 0
      }
    ],
    "selector": {
      "name": "influxGrafana"
    },
    "clusterIP": "192.168.182.76",
    "type": "ClusterIP",
    "sessionAffinity": "None"
  },
  "status": {
    "loadBalancer": {}
  }
```

However, whenever I try to access it through the proxy API, it always fails with this response.

```
http://10.32.10.44:8080/api/v1/proxy/namespaces/kube-system/services/monitoring-grafana/

Error: 'dial tcp 192.168.182.132:3000: getsockopt: no route to host'  
Trying to reach: 'http://192.168.182.132:3000/'
```

It happens on all of my services also, not just the one posted.

What could be going wrong? Is something not installed?

Comment: A couple of questions: Where are you running your cluster? Can you proxy to nodes and/or pods (just not services) or is all of the proxy functionality broken? Are you running the `kube-proxy` process on your master node?

Comment: I think the entire proxying is failing, but I see kube-proxy running on the node with the correct master endpoint on the-cli. I'm not 100% clear on proxying to a a specific node?

Comment: Have you fixed this problem? Cause i am facing a similar scenario like this.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the error you posted it seems like the traffic can not be routed from your **master** to the Docker subnet of your **node**. The easiest way to validate this is to open a shell on your master and perform a request on your *podIP:daemonPort*: `curl -I http://192.168.182.132:3000`

Each node in your cluster should be able to communicate with every other node, and every Docker subnet should be routable. For most deployments you will need to setup an extra network fabric to make this happen, like flannel or Weave.

Take a look at [Getting started from Scratch >> Network](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/scratch/#network)

---

Something else is funny. The cluster IP used by your service (192.168.182.76) and the pod IP of the endpoint (192.168.182.132) *seem* to be in the same subnet. However you need 3 different subnets:

- one for the hosts
- one for the Docker bridges (`--bip` flag of Docker)
- one for the service (`--service-cluster-ip-range=` of the API server)

Answer (score 0):

In my case I didn't realize that I have active firewall that was simply preventing access to the ports needed by kubernetes. Quick and crude solution is to run `systemctl stop firewalld` on the master and all minion nodes and of course you can just open ports needed instead